# Web API 2 giving me a 404 on a long id paramter

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I'm using Web API 2 (with MVC 5) to access some data from a MongoDb store. This is the action/method:

```
    [Route("api/container/children/{parentId}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetChildren(String parentId) {
        ObjectId containerId;
        if (!ObjectId.TryParse(parentId, out containerId)) {
            IEnumerable<Container> containers = this.Connection.GetCollection<Container>().FindAs<Container>(Query.EQ(Container.FieldNames.ParentId, containerId));
            return this.Request.CreateResponse<Container[]>(HttpStatusCode.OK, containers.ToArray());
        }

        return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
```

Calling the method from jQuery with a $.get keep getting me a 404 when calling with the parameter ObjectId.Empty (which is 000000000000000000000000), so calling this Url gives me a 404:

/api/container/children/000000000000000000000000

but calling this url works fine:

/api/container/children/0000000000000000

is there some sort of limit to the length of the (id) parameter on Web API 2?

Comment: it actually looks like a single zero less, and it works. What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a WebAPI problem.

The bug in the code is actually very simple. Remove the not (!) operator in the if condition

```
[Route("api/container/children/{parentId}")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetChildren(String parentId) {
    ObjectId containerId;
    if (ObjectId.TryParse(parentId, out containerId)) {
        ...
    }

    return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
}
```

Comment: Well, talk about being blind! Thanks!